# Can I turn a spare USB keyboard into a "macro keypad"?

Tags: windows, usb, keyboard, gaming

I am a semi-avid gamer and I have recently discovered macros.

However, unlike some gamers, I am not made of money. What I would like to do is simple, but may be hard to actually do:

- I want to turn a spare USB keyboard into a macro keypad.

If you've never seen a macro keypad, it's a little device that has *n* keys on it that are all fully programmable for macro functions.

How would I turn my spare Apple USB keyboard into a macro keypad?

Comment: +1 for question and answer. Extra keys for gaming on the cheap - right up my alley.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HID macros](http://www.hidmacros.eu/) may be what you're looking for.

From "What is it?" page:

> **Key features**
>
> - manage multiple keyboards/mouses connected to one PC
> - different key on different keyboard has assigned it's own command
> - mouse buttons on different mouses can be also used as macro trigeer - including mouse wheel
> - also game devices can trigger macros. Not only buttons, but also axis.
> - when a key activates macro, it's own beahvior (e.g. sending letter code to windows) is deactivated
> - **macro can send another keyboard keys, launch application, send commands to Flight simulators (FS9, FSX, >XPL) or activate script**
> - when no macro is assigned, keyboard/mouse works as usual

Comment: It now says *"HidMacros is dead. Welcome LuaMacros"*

Answer (score 2):

I tried [HIDMacros](http://www.2112design.com/blog/multi-keyboard-remapper/), but it didn't work. I also tried [Multi-Keyboard Macros](http://www.mediachance.com/files/MKM_install.exe), but it is paid and the trial can't save the macros (and something weird happens with the USB keyboard driver when I close the program).

[LuaMacros](http://www.hidmacros.eu/luamacros.zip) and some weird [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/ahk-install.exe) libraries: both are too complicated. [Interception](https://github.com/oblitum/Interception/releases) (download [Intercept.exe](http://octopup.org/img/code/interception/intercept.zip) after the installation): It is too basic for me, but maybe it's useful for you.

Comment: I am also following this rabbit hole at the moment and the current situation is not good indeed. Also, I'm currently having a burn out from programming so having to mess around in text files is something I would avoid if at all possible. Interception still looks like an API.

I did find Keyboard Splitter. It's been the best option so far. I did have some issues with making the settings stick through reboots and usb reconnects and such, but setting it up has been pretty convenient.
https://github.com/djlastnight/KeyboardSplitterXbox

Comment: In my case it's for sim racing so I may give xpadder of rewasd a try next