# Remap keypad keys to media controls (HIDMacros)

Tags: keyboard, macros, media, hid

I recently bought a separate numeric keypad to reprogram the keys and use it like a programmable keypad. I read [this article](http://www.instructables.com/id/Making-a-powerful-programmable-keypad-for-less-tha/). It is very informative, and it suggests you to use a program called HIDMacros.

While HIDMacros is very good, it only lets me use key combinations. Is it possible to remap keys on my numeric keypad to media controls (for example, PLAY/PAUSE, NEXT, MUTE, etc.)?

The program allows you to assign [WSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) scripts to the keys.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, have you tried to remapping them yet?

Comment: @Burgi Yes, but I can not remap the keys to media controls, such as PLAY/PAUSE.

Comment: Try [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) instead.

Comment: @Arctiic: But AutoHotKey can't tell one keyboard from the other(?) - the separate numpad from the main keyboard

Comment: *"HID Macros"* - *"the only macro software that comes ready to use with the ability to take commands from ONE specified keyboard while ignoring another."*

Comment: *"[HidMacros is dead. Welcome LuaMacros](http://www.hidmacros.eu/)"*

Comment: Related (but not for a separate numeric keypad): *[My keyboard has no "media" keys; can I control media without them?](https://superuser.com/questions/278951/my-keyboard-has-no-media-keys-can-i-control-media-without-them)*

Comment: Related: *[Can I turn a spare USB keyboard into a "macro keypad"?](https://superuser.com/questions/820136/can-i-turn-a-spare-usb-keyboard-into-a-macro-keypad)*